# Ruby Win32ole HRESULT error code:0x80040154

Tags: ruby, win32ole

I am trying to open an application: Bluezone Mainframe Emulator to take a stab at automating some mainframe processes with Ruby.

I run into an issue when trying to open the application with Win32ole. Here is my code so far:

```
require 'win32ole'

class BluezoneRunner
  attr_reader :app

  def initialize
    @type = WIN32OLE_TYPE.new('BZWhll 7.1 Type Library', 'WhllObj')
    @app = WIN32OLE.new('BZWhll.WhllObj')
  end

  def visible=(is_visible)
    @app.visible = is_visible
  end

  def close
    @app.Quit
  end
end
```

The script fails when assigning the app object with this error:

```
Uncaught exception: failed to create WIN32OLE object from `BZWhll.WhllObj'
    HRESULT error code:0x80040154
      Class not registered
    C:/RubyProjects/mksta-sandbox/bluezone-automation/run_ole.rb:9:in `initialize'
    C:/RubyProjects/mksta-sandbox/bluezone-automation/run_ole.rb:9:in `new'
    C:/RubyProjects/mksta-sandbox/bluezone-automation/run_ole.rb:9:in `initialize'
    C:/RubyProjects/mksta-sandbox/bluezone-automation/bluezone_runner.rb:3:in `new'
    C:/RubyProjects/mksta-sandbox/bluezone-automation/bluezone_runner.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am currently running Windows 10 64 bit, Ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]. The application i am trying to run sits in C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueZone\7.1.

Any help on this error would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the error in my case was caused by using a 64 bit version of Ruby.

To solve this issue, use a 32 bit (X86) version of Ruby to run this code.